# Transpose Values in Rows to Columns Python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this table:

| Year | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | Type1 | 1 |
| 2010 | Type2 | 2 |
| 2011 | Type1 | 1 |

What I am looking for instead is something like this:

| Year | Type1 | Type2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 1 | 2 |
| 2011 | 1 | 0 |

How can this be done in Python?